# CareerCup (Bloomberg): Check if string is valid based on brackets

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, strings, interview-questions, balanced-delimiters

The goal of this problem is to determine if a string with brackets is valid. Below is a summary of the question from careercup.

Check if string s is valid based on brackets

```
"(({{}}))" is a valid s 
"{[]}" is a valid s
"[{[}]]" is not valid
```

I know this is a rather basic exercise. I am looking for feedback on whether my solution is sound and efficient. I would also like to know if my code is clean. Also is there too much for a 45 minute interview? The solution is shown below.

```
public class Question_ValidStringWithBrackets
{
    public bool IsValidBracketString(String s, BracketValidator validator = null)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("A string is required");

        if (validator == null)
            validator = BracketValidator.CreateDefaultValidator();

        Stack<char> openStack = new Stack<char>();

        foreach (var curBracket in s)
        {
            if (validator.IsOpen(curBracket))
            {
                openStack.Push(curBracket);
            }
            else if (openStack.Count == 0 || validator.IsMatchingPair(openStack.Pop(), curBracket))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return openStack.Count == 0;
    }

    public class BracketValidator
    {
        private HashSet<char> openBrackets = new HashSet<char>();
        private Dictionary<char, char> closedOpenedPair = new Dictionary<char, char>();

        public void AddPair(char open, char close)
        {
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(open) || char.IsWhiteSpace(close))
                throw new ArgumentException("A bracket must be specified. An empty character is not allowed.");

            if (openBrackets.Contains(open) || openBrackets.Contains(close))
                throw new ArgumentException("Brackets exist already.");

            if (closedOpenedPair.ContainsKey(open) || closedOpenedPair.ContainsKey(close))
                throw new ArgumentException("Brackets exist already.");

            openBrackets.Add(open);
            closedOpenedPair.Add(close, open);
        }

        public Boolean IsOpen(char open)
        {
            return openBrackets.Contains(open);
        }

        public bool IsMatchingPair(char open, char close)
        {
            return closedOpenedPair.TryGetValue(open, out char actualClose) && actualClose == close;
        }

        public static BracketValidator CreateDefaultValidator()
        {
            var validator = new BracketValidator();
            validator.AddPair('{', '}');
            validator.AddPair('[', ']');
            validator.AddPair('(', ')');

            return validator;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to follow on my phone and think you have a bug. Should the else-if branch's condition be negated? Ie `! validator.IsMatchingPair(...) `

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Good catch! I was looking at my phone thinking this looks like a bug, but my test work. Yes, there should be a negation. I also had to do closedOpenedPair.Add(open, close) instead of (close, open)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Guard conditions

`ArgumentNullException` is typically thrown on incorrect usage of the API. It is not an end-user exception, so I would not bother with an exception message.

> `throw new ArgumentNullException("A string is required");`

```
throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s)); // perhaps rename 's' to 'input' or 'value'
```

For the `ArgumentException` instances you throw, I would also add the `nameof(parameterName)` to the constructor. A decent error message is relevant here, so keep the message.

You have a guard on whitespace. I don't see this in the spec. Is this a requirement? If not, allow white space as either an open or close bracket.

> `if (char.IsWhiteSpace(open) || char.IsWhiteSpace(close))`

The next guard checks on duplicate registrations. An alternative policy is to ignore a registration if already registered. This depends on whether you want your API to be error-prone or act as a sandbox for consumers.

> `if (openBrackets.Contains(open) || openBrackets.Contains(close))`

I'm missing a guard condition. I doubt `open` and `close` can be the same.

```
if (open == close)  // throw ..
```

#### Readability

You could substitute some `if` statements with a ternary operator.

```
s = s ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s));
validator = validator ?? BracketValidator.CreateDefaultValidator();
```

Redundant type declarations can be replaced by `var`. Unlike javascript, `var` is ok in C#.

> `Stack<char> openStack = new Stack<char>();`

```
var openStack = new Stack<char>();
```

Comment: Good stuff. I do have to get used to using var more often. What are your thoughts on using the actual type for function returns? For example, List<string> ids = GetStudentIds(). Depending on the implementation this could be guid, int, string, and etc.

Comment: @RockLeeroy That's an interesting question! I don't mind using a declarative type in such case. However, I'm usually greedy in the usage of `var`, and would still use it here.

Comment: I would only use the declarative type when I specifically want my variable to have another scope than the return type of the function. For instance, `IList<string> ids = GetStudentIds();` (when this methods returns `List<string>`)

Comment: ...I'm from the _`var`-everywhere-party_ :-P so I prefer `var ids = (IList<string>)GetStudentIds();` (mainly for consistency reasons with other `var`s so the code is alligned) I even do `var car = default(Car)` when I need an uninitialized variable. Because of this, I have _many_ _fans_ here ;-P